# How to add router package to Meteor js?

Tags: meteor

How to add `Router` Package to `Meteor Js`.I didn't have any idea about this so please help me.I am new to Meteor so is there any best reference for `Meteor` learn quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `meteor-router` project has shifted to [iron-router](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router)

You can use meteorite to install it. To meteorite:

```
npm install -g meteorite
```

And then you can add iron-router by:

```
mrt add iron-router
```

Answer (score 8):

With the new version of Meteor this is now:

```
$ meteor add iron:router
```

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly recommend [iron-router](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router), which can be added with just `meteor add iron-router` from within your project root directory.  However, if you install [meteorite](https://github.com/oortcloud/meteorite), it will give access to all the packages listed on [Atmosphere](https://atmosphere.meteor.com/), which include some other routing solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Metor JS does not come with support for routing (i.e. having separate pages) out-of-the-box. But it is easy to add that using the router smart package.

```
$ mrt add router
```

But before adding router, you must need to install meteorite, You can install meteorite by using this command.

```
$ npm install -g meteorite
```

If your system requires root access to install global npm packages, make sure you use the -H flag:

```
$ sudo -H npm install -g meteorite
```

Answer (score 0):

Install meteorite first. before installing the 'router' package you should install couple of other packages too. "HTML5-History-API" and "page-js-ie-support" packages. These are for the router to work in older versions of IE that doesn't support push state API.

```
mrt add HTML5-History-API
mrt add page-js-ie-support
mrt add router
```

Answer (score 0):

Iron-router appears to be neither well-engineered (i.e. you can't prevent route changing without [Monkey-patch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24367914/aborting-navigation-with-meteor-iron-router)) nor well-maintained at *this* moment. I recommend considering https://github.com/meteorhacks/flow-router/ as an alternative.