# Aborting navigation with Meteor iron-router

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I have a (client-side) router in a Meteor app, and links using the `{{pathFor}}` helper.

I am setting a `dirty` flag in the `Session` when the user changes a form field, and I want to trigger a warning and allow the user to stop navigating away from the page if the flag is set, basically like an `onunload` handler.

I've tried to do this with:

```
Router.onBeforeAction(function(pause) {
    var self = this;

    if (!this.ready()) {
        return;
    }

    if(Session.get('dirty')) {
        if(!confirm("Are you sure you want to navigate away?")) {
            pause();
        }
    }
});
```

However, whilst I get the prompt, I'm still being navigated away. That is, the `pause()` doesn't seem to stop the subsequent router action, whatever it is.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6):

From what I can tell this isn't possible with the iron-router API. What you could do however is override the Router.go method like so (somewhere in your client code):

```js
var go = Router.go; // cache the original Router.go method
Router.go = function () {
  if(Session.get('dirty')) {
    if (confirm("Are you sure you want to navigate away?")) {
      go.apply(this, arguments);
    }
  } else {
    go.apply(this, arguments);
  }
};
```

Comment: You sir, are a genius. :) It would be great if there was a slightly less hacky way to do this, but this definitely works.

Answer (score 0):

Is it somewhere specific you want to go? There is also Router.go(routeName) which will make the page point to the given routeName. What I was going for is maybe you can just force the Router to go to the current page hence neglecting the back action.

Comment: I want the user not to leave the page, i.e. I want to abort the route.

Answer (score 0):

The new behavior for iron router should make this easier because it requires a call to `this.next()` in the onBeforeAction hook (see [iron router guide](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#available-hook-methods)), so only call that when the session is not dirty or the user confirms the warning:

```
if(Session.get('dirty')) {
    if(confirm("Are you sure you want to navigate away?")) {
        this.next();
    }
} else {
    this.next();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that rediecting in `stop` works, and works even when you aren't changing routes via `Router.go` (such as by links in my application).

Here is a coffeescript implementation using a class inherited from `RouteController`

```coffee
class MyRouteController extends RouteController
  stop: ->
    # Save whether you data/form is dirty or whatever state you have in 
    # a Session variable.
    if Session.get('formIsDirty') 
      if !confirm('You have unsaved data. Are you sure you want to leave?')
        # Redirecting to the current route stops the current navigation.
        # Although, it does rerun the route, so it isn't a perfect solution.
        Router.go '/my_route'
        # Return here so we don't perform any more of the stop operation.
        return
    # Otherwise do as normal.
    super
```

Answer (score 0):

The Iron Router API doesn't offer an easy way to achieve this. There is no way to cancel an ongoing transition from an `onBeforeAction` hook. It has to be worked around by redirecting to the previous route.

```
/*
 * Adds a confirmation dialogue when the current route contains unsaved changes.
 *
 * This is tricky because Iron Router doesn't support this out of the box, and
 * the reactivity gets in the way.
 * In this solution, redirecting to the current route is abused
 * as a mechanism to stop the current transition, which Iron Router has no API
 * for. Because the redirect would trigger the onStop hook, we keep track of
 * whether to run the onStop hook or not ourselves in
 * `skipConfirmationForNextTransition`.
 *
 * When `Session.get('formIsDirty')` returns `true`, the user will be asked
 * whether he really wants to leave the route or not.
 *
 * Further, another confirmation is added in case the browser window is closed
 * with unsaved data.
 * 
 * This gist shows the basics of how to achieve a navigation confirmation,
 * also known as canceling a route transition.
 * This approach may fail if other route hooks trigger reruns of hooks reactively.
 * Maybe setting `skipConfirmationForNextTransition` to `true` could help in those
 * cases.
 */
Session.setDefault('formIsDirty', false)
const confirmationMessage = 'You have unsaved data. Are you sure you want to leave?'

// whether the user should confirm the navigation or not,
// set to `true` before redirecting programmatically to skip confirmation
let skipConfirmationForNextTransition = false
Router.onStop(function () {
  // register dependencies immediately
  const formIsDirty = Session.equals('formIsDirty', true)
  // prevent duplicate execution of onStop route, because it would run again
  // after the redirect
  if (skipConfirmationForNextTransition) {
    skipConfirmationForNextTransition = false
    return
  }
  if (formIsDirty) {
    const shouldLeave = confirm(confirmationMessage)
    if (shouldLeave) {
      Session.set('formIsDirty', false)
      return
    }
    // obtain a non-reactive reference to the current route
    let currentRoute
    Tracker.nonreactive(function () {
      currentRoute = Router.current()
    })
    skipConfirmationForNextTransition = true
    // "cancel" the transition by redirecting to the same route
    // this had to be used because Iron Router doesn't support cancling the
    // current transition. `url` contains the query params and hash.
    this.redirect(currentRoute.url)
    return
  }
})

// Bonus: confirm closing of browser window
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', event => {
  if (Session.get('formIsDirty')) {
    // cross-browser requries returnValue to be set, as well as an actual
    // return value
    event.returnValue = confirmationMessage // eslint-disable-line no-param-reassign
    return confirmationMessage
  }
})
```

An up-to-date version can be found [in this gist](https://gist.github.com/dferber90/acf560226fe76fe91534).