# How to prevent navigating to another page in meteor iron router

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I have a form page and I want to alert user if he leaves it without saving the form. 
Typically I can achieve this purpose by stating a function window.onBeforeUnload.

```
window.onBeforeUnload = function(){return 'Please save the form before navigating';}
```

But it seems doesn't work in my project using Meteor and Iron Router. 
Any suggestion?

Comment: "Another page" = "a different route on your website" or "a page on another website"?

Comment: where are you adding```window.onBeforeUnload = function(){return 'Please save the form before navigating';}```?

Comment: @PeppeL-G Another page is another route still in my website.

Comment: @MurWade I added in Template.[template_name].created = function(){...here....}. Of course, I have a boolean variable to check when to call alert function.

Comment: @aladine This question may also be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24367914/aborting-navigation-with-meteor-iron-router

Comment: Facing the same problem. Do you have any updates about it?

Answer (score 1):

This is maybe a hacky version, but it works:

```
isUnsaved = ->
  return unless @ready()
  unless confirm 'Do you really want to leave the page?'
    Router.go(@url)

Router.onStop isUnsaved,
  only: [
    'editPost'
  ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Old post, but just solved it. Here is my solution :

```
Router.route('/myPath', {
    unload: function (e, obj) {
        if(Session.get("hasChanged")){
            if (confirm("Are you sure you want to navigate away ?")) {
                // Go and do some action
            }else{
                // Redirect to itself : nothing happend
                this.redirect('/myPath');
           }
        }
    }
}
```